# Can we use Webdriver API(Webdriver Methods) along with java swing library to create an application?

Tags: java, swing, web-applications, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have created a framework which uses selenium webdriver and JUnit to update few websites on a regular interval. I am planning to give a UI and launch the application on google play/ windows. Can anyone tell me that is it possible to use selenium webdriver library and swing library to make an application which can be used by a end user?

Comment: what your exactly trying to do? From the application user will trigger the test cases? You have jenkins for it, CI.

Comment: @Ant's Yes i want the user to trigger the test case by clicking some button

Comment: Hmmm, you can do that. But it requires a bit of work. Why cant you try Jenkins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check and agree with their licenses

```
Selenium - apache 2 - http://www.seleniumhq.org/about/license.jsp
JUNIT - EPL 1 - http://junit.org/license.html
TestNG - apache 2 - http://testng.org/license
```

You can redistribute these libraries in your product but you must pay attention to what each license says. But the answer is basically yes, and you're responsible for your software and can't blame them if there's any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do that. That is, essentially, what both SeleniumIDE and Selenium Builder are - GUIs on top of Selenium. They are probably intended for a different audience than yours, but thge basic idea is no different - make it easier to run SeleniumIDE commands.